# Drag and Drop across browser window

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm implementing cross-window drag-and-drop for item ordering on collaborative site and I am unable to synchronize drags to the same list. I would need to detect whether I dropped an item to the same list to avoid "add", "remove" operations and use a single "move".

*NOTE: this problem involves two browser windows e.g. Firefox and Chrome; unless it works in that case, it's not suitable solution. Also, I'm not looking for a server based solution.*

The gist of the problem can be demonstrated by this:

```js
function update(source, className, d){
var count = source.getElementsByClassName(className)[0];
count.innerText = parseInt(count.innerText) + d;
}

var els = document.getElementsByClassName("source");
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1){
(function(el){
    el.ondragover = function(ev){
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();
    };

    el.ondrop = function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();

        var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("x/source");
        if(el.dataset.id == id){
            update(el, "self", 1);
            // how to send a value from here to dragEnd -->>
            return;
        }
    };
})(els[i]);
}

var els = document.getElementsByClassName("element");
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i += 1){
(function(el){
    el.draggable = true;
    
    el.ondragstart = function(ev){
        grabbingFrom = el.parentNode.dataset.id;
        ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "all";
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("x/source", el.parentNode.dataset.id);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ev.dataTransfer.getData("x/source")));
    }
    
    el.ondragend = function(ev){
        var self = false; // how to get a value <--- here
        if(self){
            update(el, "self", 1);
        }
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
})(els[i]);
}
```

```css
.clear { clear: both; }

.source {
float: left; border: 1px solid #000; margin: 32px;
height: 100px; width: 150px;
}

.source .element { width: 32px; height: 32px; margin: 8px;
background: #AAA; margin: 8px;
line-height: 32px; text-align: center;
}

.source .element:hover {
background: hsla(0, 70%, 70%, 1);
cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<div class="source" data-id="alpha" >
Alpha
<div class="self">0</div>
<div draggable="true" class="element">X</div>
</div>

<div class="source" data-id="beta" >
Beta
<div class="self">0</div>
<div draggable="true" class="element">X</div>
</div>
```

When you Drag from "Beta" box to a "Beta" box in cross-windows, then both "Beta" counts should be incremented. Currently only one increments. Basically how to communicate across that "Yes, I've dropped this item into a 'beta' box.". The problem boils down to sending content from ondrop event to ondragend.

I've been unable to find a suitable way to do it. Any ideas?
Or, is the answer simply that it isn't possible.

Comment: Hm, the solution should require, that the script process in one tab/window reacts to pointer events on the other, which should be impossible by definition (sandboxing). A possible solution could be using a hash/parameter string via a link, that gets dragged. The new window could process this string to perform the same action. No ideas on the implementation or cross-browser/drag-drop specs though.